# Реально ли парсить данный блок?

Tags: парсер

Прошу подсказать, на сколько реально парсить блок [с этого сайта](https://bingoboom.ru)?

На главной странице есть блок (слева на картинке), при наведении на него появляется блок с цифрами (справа на картинке). На сколько реально получить эти цифры?

Без наведения его нет в html!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в панели разработчика - что меняется при наведении мыши на блок и затем постарайтесь сделать это с помощью JS (под _этим_ я подразумеваю добавление/изменение некого атрибута, который Вы должны обнаружить).

Comment: Сделайте эмуляцию мобильного устройства, точнее планшета там не обязателен клик для появления данных: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bvdI.png

Comment: не понял, куда кликнуть на сайте чтоб увидеть такой же интерфейс как у вас в вопросе?

Comment: друзья, помогите, сам не могу реализовать ((

Comment: у меня же на скриншоте вижно что регистрация не нужна для получения даных.

Comment: Там всё есть и без наведения раскройте блоки и увидете

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как ваш вопрос достаточно широк, то я позволю себе подсказать вам, что стоит использовать для достижения результата в рамках того, что знаю.

Раз элемент появляется только при наведении на него, то значит выполняется JS код, и обычным скачиванием страницы не обойтись. На выручку тут приходит Selenium, который будет рендерить страничку.

> Примерно как это выглядит на питоне

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.ВашБраузер()
browser.get('https://bingoboom.ru/')
content = browser.find_element_by_class_name('gmroulette__rows')
```

После чего в `content` будет содержимое вашей таблички

Сам элемент содержит тривиальные теги, в которых содержатся цифры, обработать их можно простой регуляркой, предварительно получив через `content.get_attribute('innerHTML')`.

Приведенный ответ строился на том, что показывается незарегистрированным пользователям сайта, так что в вашем случае элемент может называться иначе.

Так же прочитайте [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and)
ответ, тут говорится, как симулировать наведение мышью на элемент.
Я не смог воспроизвести ваш случай полностью, так как у меня страничка генерируется уже с `gmroulette__rows`.

Удачи :)

**UPD:**
Выложил пример кода [сюда](https://pastebin.com/HGdrw8fK)

Comment: дружище, если я смогу это запустить и получить нужные цифры, ты мой спаситель! Ток разобраться бы, я с питоном ни разу дела не имел, если не сложно, можешь завершить этот ответ файлом с кодом, к которому я бы мог обратиться через php? я готов отблагодарить ;)

Comment: c питоном я не подружился еще, так что пришлось додумывать, но ответ nonForgivingJesus мне помог, спасибо!))) Решил следующим образом: на локалке поднял апач + накрутил WebDriver, ну а дальше само пошло )))

Comment: Отлично, рад, что чем-то помог)
Я вчера не успел что-то сделать, так как драйвер хрома полетел

Comment: @МитяТоДаСё прошу вас еще раз посмотреть ответ, я исправил маленькую ошибку и приложил пример кода, достающий цифры. Регулярку можете дополнить, так как я просто выбирал все цифры, не смотря на их "цвет")

Comment: есть еще один момент, который пока не получается решить... я делаю на Php, цифры получаю все ок, ток хотелось бы зациклить это дело, чтобы не загружать исполняемую страницу каждый раз по новой. Хочется открыть и получать например раз в минуту... А как реализовать не пойму...

Comment: Вы можете часть кода на питоне, отвечающую за поиск элемента, засунуть в функцию и послать таймеру, как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python)

Comment: емае, просто некогда вникать в питон, а я реал его второй раз в жизни вижу (( на пыхе никак?((

Comment: а я не знаю)) 
[Какие-то темы](http://software-testing.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/33490-kak-podruzhit-selenium-i-php/) про пыху и селениум есть, но их как-то мало, что мне кажется их вместе связать будет трудно/невозможно. Вы можете выбрать Java или C#, вроде JS тоже можно использовать вместе с селениумом, там много биндингов в другие языки. Я же его использовал вместе с питоном, так что примеры могу только на питоне приводить...

Comment: вот если бы код ))) мне в БД записать надо ( id | число | цвет | датавремя)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/393738)