# Почему скрипт не находит форму логина на этом сайте, хотя с другими сайтами всё работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```python
import mechanicalsoup

URL = "https://www.instagram.com/"

browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
login_page = browser.get(URL)

login_form = login_page.soup.find("form")

print(login_form)
```

Ошибок никаких не выдаёт, просто вывод - "None"

Еслиь брать сайт twitter с его формой логина - находит без проблем

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что инстаграм генерирует элементы страницы с помощью JS.
Если вы прочитаете главную страницу MechanicalSoup, то увидите

> It doesn’t do Javascript

В библиотеке нет браузерного движка, который выполняет JS код. Чтобы это исправить, используйте Selenium.

P.S Я недавно давал [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1016350/346233), может он вам пригодится

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что можно использовать не только Selenium, но и другие headless браузеры, например PhantomJS: https://phantomjs.org/